# General way to test restored tensorflow model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am very, very brand new to Tensorflow, and need to write a script that tests a single example on a model restored from a checkpoint file.

I was wondering if there was a general way to build a test function for a restored model without knowing all the minute details of the model.

Further, in the last section of the code below, does this look like I'm headed in the right direction? If so, how does one build 'y' without knowing details of the model by heart?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
import numpy as np
from fuel.datasets.hdf5 import H5PYDataset

ckpt_path='ckt/mnist/mnist_2017_02_23_17_22_50/mnist_2017_02_23_17_22_50_5000.ckpt'

##############################
#### Initialize Variables ####
##############################

reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(ckpt_path)
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
var=[0]*len(var_to_shape_map)
i=0
for key in var_to_shape_map:
    var[i] = tf.Variable(reader.get_tensor(key), name=key)
    #print("tensor_name: ", key)
    #print(reader.get_tensor(key))
    i=i+1
initialize=tf.global_variables_initializer()

###############################
####### Restore Model #########
###############################

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, ckpt_path)

###############################
##### Get Example to Test #####
###############################

test_set = H5PYDataset('../CNN3D/data/bmnist.hdf5', which_sets=('test',))
handle = test_set.open()
for i in range(0,100):
    test_data = test_set.get_data(handle, slice(i, i+1))
    if test_data[1][0][0]==8:
        model_idx=i
test_data = test_set.get_data(handle, slice(model_idx,model_idx+1))
data = tf.Variable(np.asarray(test_data[0][0][0]), name='data')

###############################
######## Test Example #########
###############################

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[28,28])
y = ???
sess.run(initialize)
result=sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data})
print result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators) class has a convenient set of utilities such that, if your model is wrapped around an estimator, loading and predicting from it is easy.

Overall, without some kind of coordination, this will be hard.